# Maximum length of a slice in Go

Tags: go, slice

I have the following code running in a 64-bit linux OS in a 4Gb machine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    r := make([]bool, math.MaxInt32)

    fmt.Println("Size: ", len(r))
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
Size: 2147483647
```

If I change the `math.MaxInt32` for `math.MaxUint32` I get:

```
fatal error: runtime: out of memory
```

With slice size of `math.MaxUint32` I ran out of memory, I was expecting that, but when I try using `math.MaxInt64` I get:

```
panic: runtime error: makeslice: len out of range
```

So aparently I cannot create a slice with a size of `math.MaxInt64`, which bring us to my question: If the memory is not an issue, what's the biggest slice I cant create in Go?

I remember that, in Java, raw array indexes are managed with the type `int`, so the maximum size of a raw array is the max value of an `int`, if you try to do it with `long` it will raise an exception (as far as I remember), is it the same with Go? are slice index in Go bound to one specific type?

EDIT:

I ran the test using `struct{}` instead of `bool` and allocating `math.MaxInt64` elements. Everything went as expected, and prints:

```
Size: 9223372036854775807
```

So, another question, why there are two different error messages when it seems that the error is the same (not enough memory)?

What are the conditions for each error to pop out?

Comment: So it appears that it's a matter of error message ambiguity, nothing more... :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the docs, `The elements can be addressed by integer indices 0 through len(s)-1`. This means the maximum capacity for a slice is the size of the default integer on the target build.

EDIT: From looking at the source code, it appears that there is a safety check to make sure this size of slice is at all possible:

```
func makeslice(t *slicetype, len64 int64, cap64 int64) sliceStruct {
    // NOTE: The len > MaxMem/elemsize check here is not strictly necessary,
    // but it produces a 'len out of range' error instead of a 'cap out of range' error
    // when someone does make([]T, bignumber). 'cap out of range' is true too,
    // but since the cap is only being supplied implicitly, saying len is clearer.
    // See issue 4085.
    len := int(len64)
    if len64 < 0 || int64(len) != len64 || t.elem.size > 0 && uintptr(len) > maxmem/uintptr(t.elem.size) {
        panic(errorString("makeslice: len out of range"))
    }
```

So in this case, it looks like `uintptr(len) > maxmem/uintptr(t.elem.size)` so we're not allowed to do this size of an allocation.

However when I allocate `struct{}` which takes no memory, this size is allowed:

```
func main(){
    r := make([]struct{}, math.MaxInt64)
    fmt.Println(len(r))
}
// prints 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: I'm sure that I run 64 bit Go, if I do `go version` it prints `go version go1.4 linux/amd64`

Comment: @SimonOroño what does `go env` print for GOARCH?

Comment: @SimonOroño I've looked at the source code of Go and I think I know the issue. Updating my answer.

Comment: amd64. I ran the test using struct{} and had to update the question. Please check it out :-) @Not_a_Golfer

Comment: well, if that check is made, then how I get `fatal error: runtime: out of memory` using `bool` and `math.MaxUint32`?

Comment: @SimonOroño because the `maxmem` there refers to the maximal theoretical memory allocation limit on the platform, not to the actual RAM you have on the physical machine.

Comment: @SimonOroño basically for Linux/OSX it's 128G and for Windows it's 32G for a single allocation. See `runtime/malloc.h` in the go sources.

Comment: Wait, Is Go, similar to C++ where we have to be cautious about the platform where we run. Isn't it similar to Java, where write once, run anywhere?