# Golang size of []byte in int64

Tags: go

```
//data = file in []byte 
length := len(data)
```

`length` is in type `int`. I need to find the length in `int64`. I only have the `[]byte` data of the file. How can I find the size of data in `int64`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the `int` to an `int64`:

```
l := int64(len(data))
```

The length of a slice is guaranteed to fit in an `int`. If the file is larger than what can be represented by an `int`, then it's not possible to read the entire file into a []byte.

Comment: I thought of that but a file bigger than 2gb could produce wrong results

Comment: @Thellimist Length of a slice is guaranteed to fit in an integer. The [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) does not say it directly, but it's implied.  The specification states that `len` returns an `int`. The specification states that the elements of a slice can be indexed from 0 to `len(s) -1`. It follows that the length of a slice cannot be larger than the maximum `int`.  See also the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27647793/4130971).

Comment: @Thellimist keep in mind that int/uint are 32bit on a 32bit machine and 64bit on a 64bit machine.