# Can I make the index int64 in golang's for-range iteration?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, slice

According to the [spec](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range) the

```
for idx, val range a_slice
```

statement returns `idx` as an `integer`.

Since creating a large size slice is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647737/maximum-length-of-a-slice-in-go), is there a way to chance `idx` to `int64`?

Thank you.

Comment: `integer` is not a Go type. It is `int` indeed. And `int` is either 32 or 64 bits depending on the platform, meaning if your slice is large enough to need a 64-bit index, it means you are on a 64-bit platform, so int is effectively the same size as an int64.

Comment: @SirDarius That's actually an answer not a comment.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur no, the question is whether it is possible to use the `int64` type as an index, which I don't address. I merely pointed out that int and int64 are essentially the same in that case, questioning the question's relevance. Don't forget that even though int and int64 might have the same size, the spec is very clear that they are considered as distinct types.

Comment: I'll accept the answer from icza but the first comment is the most helpful :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the [spec specifies](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) the type of index to be `int` if you use a "for" statement with a "range" clause:

```
Range expression                          1st value          2nd value

array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
string          s  string type            index    i  int    see below  rune
map             m  map[K]V                key      k  K      m[k]       V
channel         c  chan E, <-chan E       element  e  E
```

Nothing you can do about it, and nothing you should do about it. The length of the slice/array will fit into `int`.

It is not possible to make a slice bigger than max `int`. Attempting to make a larger slice with a constant expression is a compile-time error:

```
x := make([]struct{}, 3123456789)
```

Compile-time error: `len argument too large in make([]struct {})`

*Note: size of `int` is implementation-specific: it is either 32-bit or 64-bit. The constant expressions here to produce the errors are for 32-bit `int`s (the Go Playground uses 32-bit `int`s).*

If length is a runtime expression, it panics:

```
i := uint(3123456789)
y := make([]struct{}, i)
```

Runtime error: `panic: runtime error: makeslice: len out of range`

And length of array types must also fit into `int`: [Spec: Array types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types)

> The length is part of the array's type; it must evaluate to a non-negative [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type `int`.

Attempting to use a larger length is a compile-time error:

```
var x [3123456789]struct{}
type t1 [3123456789]byte
type t2 [3123456789]struct{}
```

All compile-time error: `array bound is too large`

Comment: according to spec, index is always not negative. So, in theory, it should be uint.

Comment: @db_ `int` is the general integer type, and in go you can't perform operations on values of different type. E.g. if you write `j := 3`, it will have a type of `int`, and you could not write `i + j` without having to convert the index first, e.g. `int(i) + j`.