# Finding the maximum length value of a collection that can be declared in golang using make()

Tags: go

I'm facing the error "panic: runtime error: makeslice: len out of range", while creating a dynamic array, for large values of length using "make()".

eg.

```
arr := make([]int, length)   //length is a dynamic value
```

I know, this question was already asked here ([Maximum length of a slice in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647737/maximum-length-of-a-slice-in-go)). 
But, the make method does not support maximum value of the "int" datatype in golang. They consume the length value based on (size of) struct type. 
Is there any predefined APIs available to find maximum of the length value of a collection that can be declared in golang ?

Eg:

```
maxInt := int(^uint(0) >> 1) 

arr := make([]struct{}, maxInt-1)  //accepted
arr := make([]int, maxInt-1)  //throw error
```

Comment: @Volker For your question, yes! it's doable. Golang validates the len and cap using function maxSliceCap[go1.7/src/runtime/slice.go:32]. There are  APIs to get runtime information. Though this can be achieved by using a defer function to capture the panic and recover, we can use an API which will be straight forward. Question is whether there is any exposed API which will help.

Comment: @Spartan This are just _hard_ _upper_ _limits_! There is no guarantee that there actually will be enough free memory to allocate this slice. _MaxMem is not the actual available or even physically present RAM. But you are right : If this is the question of the OP, then I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the max length of a slice, you can copy the algorithm used from the runtime package. This will take an example of the slice element to determine its size, and return the maximum slice capacity for that value type.

```
func maxSliceCap(i interface{}) int {
    _64bit := uintptr(1 << (^uintptr(0) >> 63) / 2)

    var goosWindows, goosDarwin, goarchArm64 uintptr
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "darwin":
        goosDarwin = 1
    case "windows":
        goosWindows = 1
    }

    switch runtime.GOARCH {
    case "arm64":
        goarchArm64 = 1
    }

    heapMapBits := (_64bit*goosWindows)*35 + (_64bit*(1-goosWindows)*(1-goosDarwin*goarchArm64))*39 + goosDarwin*goarchArm64*31 + (1-_64bit)*32
    maxMem := uintptr(1<<heapMapBits - 1)

    elemSize := reflect.ValueOf(i).Type().Size()
    max := maxMem / elemSize

    if int(max) < 0 {
        return 1<<31 - 1
    }

    return int(max)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/roOarwQpZL